# creating an dropdown menu with form_tag and pass the selected field to a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hiho,

I am currently programming a shift planer and encountered a problem with my checkbox.

I had a checkbox to select the department I wanted to show.
It looked like this:

```
<%= form_tag("planers", method: :get) do %>

<%= select_tag "department", options_from_collection_for_select(@departments, "id", "name")%>

<%= submit_tag "go", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
```

and this worked perfectly fine. but it created ugly URL.

e.g. localhost:3000/planers?utf8=✓&department=1

But I wanted to change my URL to something like this. localhost:3000/1 for the department with ID 1. That was the easy part.

I changed this to my routes.rb

```
get ':department(/:week)' => 'planers#index', as: :week_planer
```

I take 1 parameter for the department and one optional one for the week that schould be displayed.

I adjusted my button that shows the next week to this

```
<%= link_to "prev", week_planer_path(department: params['department'],week: @week+1) , class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

this also works perfectly fine. The big question is:

**how do I adjust my form_tag in a way that it calls a defined route with the selected field as a param?**

I definately want to use get, because every department schould have a direct link to their shift planer. 
(I guess in case this can only be done with post I could define the same route as post and get and give it different path names so localhost:3000/1 still works)

```
<%= form_tag week_planer_path([:department]), method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag "department", options_from_collection_for_select(@departments, "id", "name")%>
  <%= submit_tag "go", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
 <% end %>
```

but it produces something like this:

http://localhost:3000/department?utf8=%E2%9C%93&department=1

I spend like 6h+ on researching on this but i couldnt come up with a solution. I hope someone knows a solution, if possible w/o js.

if someone wants to take a look on my repo, here u go:

https://github.com/Elux91/shift-planer

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is your only option here, because you are dynamically changing the form action based on what the user selects in the drop down. This is client side DOM manipulation, so it can't be done in plain HTML.

I think the most elegant way to do this, is to place the path you want into a data-attribute on each option in the select. Like so:

```
<%= form_tag "", id: "department-form", method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag "department", options_for_select(@departments.map {|department| [department.name, department.id, { 'data-url' => week_planer_path(department: department.id) }] })
  <%= submit_tag "go", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Now set the form's action property to the value of that data-url attribute:

```
$("#department").change(function() {
  var form_url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
  $('#department-form').prop('action', form_url);
});
```

Now when you submit the form, you will end up at the right place. (Hopefully!)

To get rid of the form fields in the URL, make the form a POST, and set your route definition to respond to a POST.

Comment: thx. I haven't worked with JS yet. that was my task for the WE. gonna come back to the problem once I am familiar with JS.

Comment: I haven't tryed yet, i was quite busy, but i was able to learn the basics of JS and jquery and i think i understand what it is supposed to do. I'll tell you when i managed to get it to work, thx again

Comment: hey @rlarcombe finally managed to work on this problem and your solution does work. the problem is is still requires you to click the button and if you do so it produces an url like this: http://localhost:3000/2?utf8=%E2%9C%93&department=2

Comment: hey @rlarcombe. i edited too much. here is the hole answer: finally managed to work on this problem and your solution does work. the problem is is still requires you to click the button and if you do so it produces an url like this: http://localhost:3000/2?utf8=%E2%9C%93&department=2.  I'd rather have it render the hole page on select. unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. If I do something like this: $.ajax({
   url: form_url, 
   dataType: "html"
  }); it doesnt render the result back to the view, only only gives the result back to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately form submission works this way.
It calls the action attribute (in this case Rails puts 'http://localhost:3000/department' for you as the action) and append all input field values as query params.

You can only use Javascript to do what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the first answer, will only work once the form is changed. But you can just initialize the method given on form load so that it works properly with the first selected item.

```
<%= form_tag "", id: "department-form", method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag "department", options_for_select(@departments.map {|department| [department.name, department.id, { 'data-url' => week_planer_path(department: department.id) }] })
  <%= submit_tag "go", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var form_url = $('#department').find(':selected').data('url');
  $('#department-form').prop('action', form_url);
});

$("#department").change(function() {
  var form_url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
  $('#department-form').prop('action', form_url);
});
```